# Perseo rule can't be created: Event type not found

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-perseo

I'm emulating a dummy scenario to play around with Perseo and Orion.  I'm using 4 docker containers: Mongo, Orion, Perseo FE, and Perseo Core. All of them running healthy.

The steps that I'm doing are:

1. First, I create the entity with POST to Orion (`localhost:1026/v2/entities`). This entity looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "DummyEvent1",
  "type": "DummyEvent",
  "identification": {
    "value": "default",
    "type": "String"
  }
}
```

2. Second, I create a subscription with a POST to Orion (`localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions`) in order to push this `DummyEvent` from Orion to Perseo:

```
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about DummyEvent1",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "DummyEvent1",
        "type": "DummyEvent"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://perseo-fe:9090/notices"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "identification"
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Third, If I GET all the subscriptions in Orion (`localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions`), I can see that Orion is forwading the `DummyEvent` correctly to Perseo:

```
{
  "id": "5ca5c18ab07f5ae96aa12152",
  "description": "A subscription to get info about DummyEvent1",
  "status": "active",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "DummyEvent1",
          "type": "DummyEvent"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": []
     }
  },
  "notification": {
    "timesSent": 1,
    "lastNotification": "2019-04-04T08:34:18.00Z",
      "attrs": [
        "identification"
      ],
      "attrsFormat": "normalized",
      "http": {
        "url": "http://perseo-fe:9090/notices"
      },
      "lastSuccess": "2019-04-04T08:34:18.00Z",
      "lastSuccessCode": 200
  }
}
```

4. Fourth, But the problem appears when I try to POST a rule in Perseo (`localhost:8080/perseo-core/rules`) using this `DummyEvent`:

```
{
    "name": "dummy_rule",
    "text": "select * from DummyEvent",
    "action": {
        "type": "update",
        "parameters": {
            "name": "identification",
            "value": "updatedValue",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Perseo tells me this:

```
{
    "error": "Failed to resolve event type: Event type or class named 'DummyEvent' was not found [select * from DummyEvent]"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!